# Find value in column and get value below it

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm searching on sheet2 in column A for "Dept:" and if i find it returns the value below that row, how do i find it?

Here's my formula for finding row match:

```
=MATCH("Dept:",Sheet2!A1:A82,0)
```

EDIT HERE'S MY ANSWER:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!A" & CELL("row",INDEX(Sheet2!A1:A82,MATCH("Dept:",Sheet2!A1:A82,0))) +1)
```

Comment: A bit confused - column A?

Comment: @BigBen yes I'm searching the whole column A for the word "Dept:" and if a match is found, it returns the row number. this formula is on another sheet by the way. How would I write the formula to include "A" & row"

Comment: `="A" & MATCH("Dept:",Sheet2!A1:A82,0)` note that this is basically pulled directly from your comment above by just swapping `row` with the equation that you already had that returns the row

Comment: @urdearboy this formula is on sheet1, how do i do it for that sheet?

Comment: I dont follow. You want to also know the sheet name? Please let us know what the exact final output is - given what you have told us, you have 2 solutions that will show you `A#`. If these don't work, it is because you are not telling us something

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return the absolute cell reference, you can use `CELL()`:

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(Sheet2!A1:A82,MATCH("Dept:",Sheet2!A1:A82,0)))
```

Comment: I don't want the absolute reference, i need to find the "Dept:" on sheet2 and find the value below it. ^^ only return the reference, i need the value.

Comment: @ThisGuyJustNeedsHelp that's not what your OP asks. Can you please edit to include what you are trying to do? This does answer how to find column and row. The cell below it can be found just by adding `offset()`